# Would like a Boolean result from a SQL table search C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to use a C# SQL search and then get a Boolean result on whether or not the item was found. I have the search statement working but not the Boolean result portion.

EX: If i have a table with a column called @Names with the names, A,B,C but i search for Name D, how or can i get a Boolean result to come back and save false in a Boolean variable.

Comment: What does the `bool` represent?  Whether or not any results were returned?

Comment: Yes, whether or not the search found what it was looking for

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this approach:

```
string query = @"
select case when exists (
    select 1
    from MyTable
    where Name='D' -- This is the condition you are checking
) then 1 else 0 end";

bool exists;
using(var command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
{
     exists = Convert.ToBoolean(command.ExecuteScaler());
}
```

You can now use the [`ExecuteScalar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx) method, and cast the result to `bool` for the result of your query.

Comment: Sorry im still a bit new to C# with SQL, Is this a query or code to be put in the main method. Alsp when you have the select 1, what is 1 supposed to be?

Comment: @user1429684 the above is the SQL Query you run.

Comment: @user1429684 Put this query into the `CommandText` property of your SQL command object. `select 1` is a typical shortcut for the selection list of throw-away queries, such as ones used in the `exists` conditions.

Comment: Sorry to complicate the issue but what if i wish to have a value(or two) checked when it is entered by a user into a textbox

Comment: @user1429684 You'd need to pass parameters to your query then. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx) is an example illustrating how it is done.

Comment: If its not to much trouble would you mind explaining to me the Items needed for that. I cant tell what the connection is, or the command Text, i know what the command string is

Comment: @user1429684 Did you see the link from my previous comment? It has a complete example.

Comment: @user1429684 Take a look at an [`ADO.NET` tutorial](http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorial/AdoDotNet), it explains the terminology pretty clearly.

Comment: THANK YOU, you have been a great help, all of you